# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when viewchild property is used as another component's input parameter

Tags: angular

I have a viewchild property in the parent component, referencing a random element in the template.

And I want the child component to have some access to the nativeElement of that, just like this:

```
export class MyParentComponent {
    @ViewChild('randomElement') randomElement!: ElementRef;


<section>
    <div #randomElement></div>

    <my-child-component [childInput]="randomElement"></my-child-component>
</section>
```

However Angular doesn't like it, it throws the error `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` as the child component first initializes with an undefined childInput property, but then viewInit kicks in, updates viewChild and suddenly the child component does have a defined childInput property.

What's the best way to do this? I need to have access to that randomElement, as the child component requires to know some of its width/height/offset properties.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by manually calling `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` in `ngAfterViewInit` like this:

```
constructor (private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
...
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
```